# En una consulta agregar dato solo al primer dato obtenido - SQL

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

tengo una tabla con X número de registros, pero me interesa que solo a el primer registro se le pueda dar un dato extra, **esto puede ser por campo identificador**, es decir, el identificador menor, esto solo a manera de identificar que fue el primer registro en ser obtenido, al mismo tiempo obtenga el resto de los datos. Supongo que sería con `CASE` pero no estoy seguro.

Gracias.

Ejemplo de salida:

```
------------------------------
| ID  |Nombre    | Expr1     |
------------------------------
| 4   |Omar      | 1         |
| 9   |Juan      | 0         |
| 13  |Maria     | 0         |
| 14  |Lupita    | 0         |
```

-Donde `Expr1` sería el dato extra generado por la consulta SQL.

Supondría que sería algo asi, pero la sintaxis es erronea:

```
SELECT id, nombre, CASE id WHEN MIN(id) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END 'Expr1' FROM tbl_contenido
```

Comment: Sin los datos de prueba y la consulta que probaste, es difícil responder con precisión. Esencialmente, las bases de datos relacionales no preservan el orden en los resultsets a menos que indiques un criterio de búsqueda. Por favor, amplía el contenido de tu pregunta [editándola](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/166339/edit) y añadiendo la información faltante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un error de concepto en tu pregunta ¿Cual es el primer dato obtenido?

En realidad, en una base de datos, no hay un primer dato obtenido. Ningun motor de base de datos asegura que el primer registro obtenido sea el primero de ningun tipo, a menos que hagas un order by. No hay un orden en los registros, a menos que le agregues un timestamp, o la base este configurada para guardar logs de entrada y veas el timestamp de entrada de los registros.

Dicho todo esto, dado que este respuesta en realidad no contesta tu pregunta, podrias explicar el porque de agregar algo a un registro que en realidad no sabes cual es, o si sabes cual es, explicar que query intentaste hasta ahora o porque es el primer registro? Una vez hecho eso, edito la respuesta con lo que necesites.

Comment: Pues el punto es que al menos un resultado tenga un extra identificador, supongo que seria mediante el Identificador autoincrementable.

Comment: y para que? con que idea? tal vez si explicas mejor el problema, encontremos una mejor solucion. Sobretodo si dices a que queres llegar con eso

Comment: Necesito enviar datos a un DataSet en Vb.net, esto mediante una consulta SQL, en el cual uno de cualquiera de todos los registros necesita un campo Extra, ya que es para un carrusel de imagenes (Este necesita una imagen para comenzar), ese es el punto del parametro extra. Cuando este parámetro este disponible la idea es que lo tome como referencia a ser la imagen principal o de inicio.

Comment: la idea sería hacer algo como lo siguiente: `SELECT id, titulo, CASE id WHEN MIN(id) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END 'extra' FROM tbl_contenido` pero la sintaxis es erronea.

Comment: Me parece que tu problema esta en como usas ese carrousel.. no creo que necesites un campo extra, ya que todo el mundo va a tener ese campo extra una vez que lo agregues, por mas valor que tenga.... @AbrahamMontes